# spring boot arguments have spaces and can not parse correctly

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot non web project , main purpose is used as a shell to send email message.
Uasge:

```
send-email-shell-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -to foo@bar.com -subject "hello world" -attach /tmp/pom.xml
```

but I found actually the arguments is

```
[-to, foo@bar.com, -subject, hello, world, -attach, /tmp/pom.xml]
```

and because I want to convert args to map, odd index is key, even index is value, so I check args length first, if `args.length%2!=0` will throw `Exception`. So how could I do to process subject content with space correctly?

Comment: parse it and check if your string starts with "-" and take next token if its not "-" as argument

Comment: Thanks! please see my post below.

Answer (score 1):

See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

the arguments are specified with `=`

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myproject
```

So try

```
$ java -jar send-email-shell-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -to=foo@bar.com -subject="hello world"
```

Comment: but it's a executable jar, and I want to be a normal shell script e.g `ls -l`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @SMA 
Below is my way as you suggest

```
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String key = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if(args[i].startsWith("-")){
            key = args[i].replaceFirst("-+", ""); // -from --> from
            map.put(key, null);
        }else{
            map.put(key, (map.get(key)==null?"":map.get(key)+" ")+args[i]);
        }
    }
```

arguments is

```
[-to, foo@bar.com, -subject, hello, world]
```

map is

```
{subject=hello world, to=foo@bar.com}
```